# Which method is called when someone tries to connect using WifiP2PManager.connect(Channel, WifiP2pConfig,ActionListener)?

Tags: android, networking, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am tring to setup WIFI P2P on 2 devices using

`manager.addLocalService(channel, service, ActionListener)`

and then connect both devices using

`manager.connect(channel, config, ActionListener)`.

I would like to know which method is called before the popup to accept/reject connection is shown on the target device. All I was able to find was `onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo p2pInfo)`, but it is called after the connection is established.

I basically want to receive the "instance name" of the device trying to connect to me using WIFI P2P and then reject the connection request without showing system dialog(that allows the user to accept/reject connection).

I can't anything that can help me do this on docs or any other place. If anyone knows how to do it or can point me in the right direction then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I can put the instancename and devicename (of device I want to connect to) in `Map` that is passed when setting up service. From other device I can retrieve map of all devices available using [this](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html#discover) and find the instancename of one I need.